# Using InsertUI and UpdateSelectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to use InsertUI and updateSelectizeInput methods in the server function as part of my app, primarily since my list of choices is so large.

```
library(shiny)

baby_names <- babynames::babynames %>% 
  distinct(name) %>%
  .[["name"]] %>% 
  sort()

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  id = "babies"
  insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
           ui = tags$div(list(
             selectizeInput("babynames", label = "Baby Names!", multiple = TRUE, choices = NULL, width = '400px',
                            options = list(placeholder = 'Type a baby name.'))
           ), 
           immediate = TRUE, 
           id = id))

    updateSelectizeInput(
      session, inputId = "babynames",
      choices = baby_names,
      server = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not getting much success out of this, as the selectizeInput is displayed but the dropdown options are not shown. How should I address this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation of `insertUI`:

> This function allows you to dynamically add an arbitrarily large UI object into your app, whenever you want, as many times as you want. **Unlike renderUI(), the UI generated with insertUI is not updatable as a whole: once it's created, it stays there.** Each new call to insertUI creates more UI objects, in addition to the ones already there (all independent from one another). To update a part of the UI (ex: an input object), you must use the appropriate render function or a customized reactive function

(I added the bold font)

Therefore, you should use `renderUI` instead.